# In ReactJS, not getting output on DOM via using axios method

Tags: reactjs

I wish to display the 'name' property from the given API in a list on DOM. The only output i am getting on DOM is 'hello'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        Posts: []
    }
    
    async componentDidMount(){
        const { data: posts } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        console.log(posts);
        this.setState({ posts });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.Posts.map( i => <li> {i.name} </li> )  }
                hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: watch for keys `Posts` and `posts`, stick with only one of them, that's why it's not working probably

Comment: `Posts` is not the same as `posts`, notice the casing. `this.state.posts.map(...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`this.setState({ posts });`

to

`this.setState({ Posts: posts });`

OR

if you still want to use `this.setState({ posts });` as it is, then you have to update

`{ this.state.Posts.map( i => <li> {i.name} </li> )  }`

to

`{ this.state.posts.map( i => <li> {i.name} </li> )  }`